# Writing output from netstat and findstr to text file

Tags: windows, cmd

I am currently having a problem writing the output of a netstat and findstr command to a text file. The command works fine itself when not having it's output being written to a file (`netstat -a | findstr "ESTABLISHED"`), or when only the netstat command is used (`netstat -a >> task3.txt`).

This is the command I've written which does not write to the file: `netstat -a | findstr "ESTABLISHED" >> task3.txt`.

Comment: Did you wait long enough for `netstat -a` to complete. This worked on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: ```netstat -a``` itself works when writing to a file. It's ```netstat -a | findstr "ESTABLISHED"``` that doesn't work when writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This will run in a `windows` `cmd` command line or `batch-file`. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-NetTCPConnection | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Established' } >>'.\task9.txt'"
```